# What is int* and long* of objective-c equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I am trying to port a library of native iOS in Xamarin iOS by creating the binding library. I followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/) tutorial. But I am stuck at the point of building the solution.

I had replaced `void*` with `IntPtr` because objective-c equivalent of `void*` is `IntPtr` in C#.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

`int32_t*` and `int64_t*` of objective-c in C# to be more precise.

Comment: int32_t* and int64_t * of objective-c in c# to be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the purpose of the pointers: to pass *variables* to a method/function so the callee can alter the value; or for general pointer arithmetic.

In the first case if the use is to return multiple values from then [an `out` parameter is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). If the use is more general and the parameter is used to read & write the passed variable then use [a `ref` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

In the second case you should first consider redesigning your algorithms not to use pointers, which is more in keeping with the C# model. If you really need to perform general pointer manipulation then you need to use [`unsafe` code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) and then the exact same [pointer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types) you require are available.